Google Translate won't revert back to default language when switching pages
I'm using Google translate on a Webflow site. The user can click a dropdown button and switch between several languages.
If they switch to another language and go to a new page the new language is shown. However, if they switch back to English and switch to a new page, the language will still be in the old language.


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" defer></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');
    }

    function triggerHtmlEvent(element, eventName) {
      var event;
      if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
        element.fireEvent('on' + event.eventType, event);
      }
    }
  
  jQuery('.lang-select').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor click behavior
    var theLang = jQuery(this).attr('data-lang');
    jQuery('.goog-te-combo').val(theLang).change();  // Set the new language and trigger change event
    window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');  // Navigate to the new page
    location.reload();
});

  </script>



I would like the user to be able to revert back to English and have the Google translate cookie be updated to reflect that change.
